# Add a value to a new column on Data frame that depends on the value on another Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames df1 and df2. df1 has entries of amounts spent by users and each user can have several entries with different amounts values. 
The second data frame just holds the information of every users(each user is unique in this data frame).
i want to create a new column on df1 that includes the country value of each unique user from df2.
Any help will be appreciated

```
 df1

    name_id      Dept       amt_spent
0   Alex-01      Engineering    5
1   Bob-01       Finance        5
2   Charles-01   HR             10
3   David-01     HR             6
4   Alex-01      Engineering    50

df2
   name_id   Country
0   Alex-01      UK
1   Bob-01       USA
2   Charles-01   GHANA
3   David-01     BRAZIL


Result

    name_id      Dept         amt_spent  Country
0   Alex-01      Engineering  5          UK     
1   Bob-01       Finance      5          USA
2   Charles-01   HR           10         GHANA
3   David-01     HR           6          BRAZIL
4   Alex-01      Engineering  50         UK
```

Comment: have looked at the merge function?

Comment: Can use .map since they are unique in the second

Comment: import pandas as pd
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Alex-01','Engineering',    5],
        ['Bob-01','Finance',   5],
        ['Charles-01','HR',  10],
        ['David-01','HR',   6],
        ['Alex-01','Engineering',   50]], columns=['name_id', 'Dept', 'amt_spent'])
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Alex-01','UK'],
        ['Bob-01','USA'],
        ['Charles-01','GHANA'],
        ['David-01','BRAZIL']], columns=['name_id', 'Country'])
    df = pd.merge(df1, df2)
    df

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2)
```